# Changing programmatically the text of a 3D TextNode in SceneKit using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scntext

So I have placed a 3D Text Node in my SCN scene and I would like to change the value of the Text property later in my application

SceneKit Inspector

[image]

Above is how I change the value of the text from the inspector but is there  a way to do it programmatically? thank you

Comment: Did you link your node on your SKScene? If so, what's the variable name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you instantiate a "3D Text" object from the Object Library in Xcode, what you get is a [`SCNNode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode) that has a [`SCNText`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntext) as its [`geometry`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407966-geometry).

```
if let textGeometry = textNode.geometry as? SCNText {
    textGeometry.string = "something"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you have linked your text node with your game scene, programmatically you can do:

```
textNode.geometry.string = "your string"
```

It should work!

Comment: I tried this but I get : Value of type 'SCNGeometry' has no member 'string'

Comment: @JosephHajjar Is it a SCNText ?

Comment: I don't think so, I think it's  SCNNode, from the inspector it looks like this http://imgur.com/HyGKCjl and the image above shows the inspector when I click on it with  an additional Text Attribute, but I can't find a way  to get a reference to it programmatically...

Comment: @JosephHajjar on your variable can you just do var.string = "your text"?

Comment: I'm getting my var like this
`let textNode = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "container", recursively: true)!`
 so It's a SCNNode and I can't use textNode.string

Comment: @JosephHajjar I would have a look at this problem tomorrow morning

Comment: Cast the result of childNode with `if let textNode = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "container", recursively: true) as? SCNText { textNode.geometry.string = "whatever" }`

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.  Assume you've added a 3D Text Node in interface builder and it's called "CountDownText" in the node hierarchy.

In the relevant view controller, I have two properties:

```
var countDownText: SCNNode!
var theCountDownText: SCNText!
```

Later, bind the node from the interface builder to the code (in a set up node function):

```
countDownText = scnScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "CountDownText", recursively: true)
theCountDownText = countDownText.geometry as! SCNText
```

Any time you want to change the display text of that node, you can just do as follows:

```
theCountDownText.string = "text"
```